# Python Tkinter Input Box

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day.
I am trying to create my own input box for use in my project.
basically what i am trying to do is run my main form which will call the second. the user will provide some data on the second and when the press the ok/close button on the second for the data will be passed back to the first. similar in functionality to the inputbox.
here is what i have created, but being new to python i am not sure where i am going wrong/nor can i quick figure out when to put the return.

> My Class is here

---

```
import tkinter as tk
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.myLabel = tk.Label(top, text='Enter a Grouping Name')
        self.myLabel.pack()
        self.myEntryBox = tk.Entry(top)
        self.myEntryBox.focus_set()
        self.myEntryBox.pack()
        self.mySubmitButton = tk.Button(top, text='OK', command=self.DestWin)
        self.mySubmitButton.pack()
    def DestWin(self):
        self.top.destroy()
```

---

> The method to call it is here

---

```
abc=configurator.MainWindow(root)
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you are trying to get values from one window to another, below you can find an extended example based on your code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.myLabel = tk.Label(top, text='Enter a Grouping Name')
        self.myLabel.pack()
        self.myEntryBox = tk.Entry(top)
        self.myEntryBox.focus_set()
        self.myEntryBox.pack()
        self.mySubmitButton = tk.Button(top, text='OK', command=self.DestWin)
        self.mySubmitButton.pack()
    def DestWin(self):
        # call callback function setting value in MyFrame
        self.callback(self.myEntryBox.get())
        self.top.destroy()


    def set_callback(self, a_func):
        self.callback = a_func



class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.pack()

        self.myLabel1 = tk.Label(parent, text='Click OK to enter the group name')
        self.myLabel1.pack()
        self.mySubmitButton1 = tk.Button(parent, text='OK', command=self.get_group_name)
        self.mySubmitButton1.pack()

    def get_group_name(self):
        mw = MainWindow(None)

        # provide callback to MainWindow so that it can return results to MyFrame
        mw.set_callback(self.set_label)



    def set_label(self, astr = ''):
        self.myLabel1['text'] = astr





root = tk.Tk()

mf = MyFrame(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The screenshot:

[image]

The text from the right window, when OK is pressed, will be shown in the left window. This is achieved through callbacks. `MainWindow` takes a callback function, and when you press OK, it is executed. The callback is `set_label` from MyFrame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this does exactly what i asked for, thank you. i tried voting this up but i need more that 15 rep.
but this is the answer